# creating after delete trigger with two different database using database link

Tags: postgresql-9.1, database-trigger, dblink

Created two tables in two different database(TestDb1 and TestDb2) in the same server.I wrote after delete trigger on "Error_Master" table`.if i delete record in "ERROR_MASTER" table which is in TestDB1 that trigger insert records in "ERROR_MASTER_LOG" table which exists in TestDb2.

My dblink->dblink('dbname=TestDb2 port=5432 host=192.168.0.48 user=postgres password=soft123')

### DB->TestDb1

```
CREATE TABLE public."ERROR_MASTER"
(
  "MARKERID" integer NOT NULL,
  "FILENAME" character varying,
  "RECNO" integer,
  "ERRORCODE" character varying,
  "USERID" character varying,
  "ID" integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "ERR_MASTER_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
 )
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

### DB->TestDb2

```
CREATE TABLE public."ERROR_MASTER_LOG"
(
  "MARKERID" integer NOT NULL,
  "FILENAME" character varying,
  "RECNO" integer,
  "ERRORCODE" character varying,
  "USERID" character varying,
   "ID" integer NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT "ERR_MASTER_Log_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"),
  "Machine_IP" character varying,
  "DELETED_AT" timestamp
 )
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

ALTER TABLE public."ERROR_MASTER_LOG"
  OWNER TO postgres;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE public."ERROR_MASTER_LOG" TO postgres;


CREATE INDEX "IDX_ERROR_MASTER_LOG_MARKERID_RECNO"
ON public."ERROR_MASTER_LOG"
USING btree
("MARKERID" COLLATE pg_catalog."default", "RECNO" COLLATE pg_catalog."default", round("X1"::numeric, 2));
```

i tried below trigger in TestDb1 for inserting record in a table which exists in another database TestDb2 using dblink. It shows schema "old" does not exist.Please help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mdp_error_master_after_delete()
      RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
   perform dblink_connect('host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=TestDB2');
   perform dblink_exec('INSERT INTO "ERROR_MASTER_LOG"("MARKERID","ID")
       values('||OLD."MARKERID"||','||OLD."ID"')');
        perform dblink_disconnect();
        RETURN OLD;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE NOTICE  'insert_new_sessions SQL ERROR: %', SQLERRM;
      RETURN NULL;
     END;
   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
   COST 100;
   ALTER FUNCTION mdp_error_master_after_delete()
   OWNER TO postgres;  

CREATE TRIGGER ERROR_MASTER_CHANGES
  AFTER DELETE
  ON "ERROR_MASTER"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE mdp_error_master_after_delete()
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible. And avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers, they are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: They created these tables in production environment.Not able to change now.please fix these error  schema "old" does not exist